# How to force UpperCase in a VS2008 snippet?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, properties, code-snippets, casing

I've settled on the following style of creating properties (with a backing field):

```
private _firstName;
public string FirstName
{
    get { return _firstName; }
    set { _firstName = value; }
}
```

Given that the name of the property is similar to the name of the backing field, I've improved the built in `prop` snippet to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>prop</Title>
      <Author>Frank Rizzo</Author>
      <Description>Code snippet for property and backing field - changed one (not the original).</Description>
      <Shortcut>prop</Shortcut>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal>
          <ID>type</ID>
          <ToolTip>Property type</ToolTip>
          <Default>int</Default>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
          <ID>property</ID>
          <ToolTip>Property name</ToolTip>
          <Default>MyProperty</Default>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
          <ID>field</ID>
          <ToolTip>The variable backing this property</ToolTip>
          <Default>myVar</Default>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
      <Code Language="CSharp"><![CDATA[private $type$ _$field$;

    public $type$ $field$
    {
        get { return _$field$;}
        set { _$field$ = value;}
    }
    $end$
            ]]></Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

This works to a degree, but the casing of the backing field and the property name is always the same, where as in my convention, the backing field is camel-cased, where as the property name is pascal-cased.

So my question is this: does the snippet syntax have a way to change the first letter of the property, so that the snippet might comply with my convention?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible (yet).

Hopefully, it will be possible in a future version of Visual Studio.

Comment: SLaks is correct, snippets just aren't well supported yet in many respects. (No editor in the IDE, **still** in VS 2010 is evidence of this)

Answer (score -2):

```
<CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <Header>
    <Title>Code File Header</Title>
    <Author>Муся</Author>
    <Shortcut>codehead</Shortcut>
    <Description>Гавнокодец</Description>
    <SnippetTypes>
      <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
    </SnippetTypes>
  </Header>
  <Snippet>
    <Declarations>
      <Literal>
        <ID>Name</ID>
        <Default>Header</Default>
      </Literal>
      <Literal>
        <ID>LowerName</ID>
        <Default>header</Default>
      </Literal>
      <Literal>
        <ID>Type</ID>
        <Default>object</Default>
      </Literal>
    </Declarations>
    <Code Language="CSharp">
      <![CDATA[
        public $Type$ $Name$
        {
            get { return $LowerName$; }
            set
            {
                $LowerName$ = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("$Name$");
            }
        }
        $Type$ $LowerName$;
      ]]>
    </Code>
  </Snippet>
</CodeSnippet>
```

Comment: Please specify what the question-asker needs to do outside of your code block.

Comment: Your code doesn't look like it's actually doing any case-conversion.